# Refering to a particular parent, in case of multiple, and then retrieving its attribute

Tags: tactic

If an `sobject` has more then one parent, how do we lexically refer any one its parent in order to get its attributes?

I need it to write a naming convention for that particular `sobject`.

The `sobject` and its parent `sobject`s are connected in the schema by `code`.

What I tried was something like:

```
{project.code}/{sobject.parent01_code}/{sobject.code}/{context}
```

which works but `{sobject.parent01_code}` is not what I want, because it is not quite self-explanatory and cryptic to be used for naming of files and directories.

I rather want to something like `../{sobject.parent01.name}/..` or `../{sobject.parent01_code.name}/..` which returns `Reported Error: "too many values to unpack"` error.

So how can I achieve such a thing? Given, if I am not wrong, the absence of a full brunt expression language in the setting of naming conventions, which, if a present, would enable something like `@SOBJECT(parent01["code", {sobject.parent01_code}]).name`.

These are two separate questions but put into one because it relates to one particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

This used to be unsolved in earlier versions of tactic. In 4.1 however, you can also use the expression language in the braces.

ex: {project.code}/{@GET(example/some_stype.name)}/versions

If some_stype is the parent of to the current stype's, you'll get the corresponding sobject's name.